# Algorithmic Benchmark: What is the reason for unevenness (spike) in the runtime graph by the number of qubits of the Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm?

Tags: deutsch-jozsa-algorithm, qiskit-runtime, scalability

I am testing quantum simulators based on runtime and memory usage. I impelmented Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm as follows in Qiskit:

```python
def main():
    """
    Executes the Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm using the specified
    number of qubits and shots.
    """
    oracle = deutsch_jozsa_oracle(args.num_qubits)
    circuit = deutsch_jozsa_algorithm(oracle)
    backend = get_backend(args.provider, args.backend)
    transpiled_circuit = transpile(circuit, backend)
    backend.run(transpiled_circuit, shots=args.num_shots).result()

def deutsch_jozsa_oracle(num_qubits: int) -> QuantumCircuit:
    """
    Creates a quantum circuit representing the oracle for the Deutsch-Jozsa
    algorithm.

    Args:
        num_qubits (int): The number of qubits in the circuit.

    Returns:
        QuantumCircuit: The quantum circuit representing the oracle.
    """
    oracle = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits + 1)

    if randint(0, 1):
        oracle.x(num_qubits)

    if randint(0, 1):
        return oracle

    on_states = sample(range(2**num_qubits), 2**num_qubits // 2)

    def add_cx(circuit, bit_string):
        for qubit, bit in enumerate(reversed(bit_string)):
            if bit == "1":
                circuit.x(qubit)
        return circuit

    for state in on_states:
        oracle = add_cx(oracle, f"{state:0b}")
        oracle.mcx(list(range(num_qubits)), num_qubits)
        oracle = add_cx(oracle, f"{state:0b}")

    return oracle


def deutsch_jozsa_algorithm(oracle: QuantumCircuit) -> QuantumCircuit:
    """
    Implements the Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm.

    Args:
        oracle (QuantumCircuit): The oracle circuit representing the function
        to be evaluated.

    Returns:
        QuantumCircuit: The circuit implementing the Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm.
    """
    num_qubits = oracle.num_qubits - 1
    algorithm = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits + 1, num_qubits)
    algorithm.x(num_qubits)
    algorithm.h(range(num_qubits + 1))
    algorithm.compose(oracle, inplace=True)
    algorithm.h(range(num_qubits))
    algorithm.measure(range(num_qubits), range(num_qubits))
    return algorithm
```

and as follows in Cirq:

```python
def main():
    """
    Executes the Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm using the specified
    number of qubits and shots.
    """
    qubits = LineQubit.range(args.num_qubits + 1)
    oracle = deutsch_jozsa_oracle(qubits)
    circuit = deutsch_jozsa_algorithm(qubits, oracle)
    backend = get_backend(args.provider, args.backend)
    backend.run(
        circuit, repetitions=args.num_shots
    )

def deutsch_jozsa_oracle(qubits: list[LineQubit]):
    """
    Constructs the oracle circuit for the Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm.

    Args:
        qubits (list[LineQubit]): The list of qubits to be used in the circuit.

    Returns:
        Circuit: The constructed oracle circuit.
    """
    num_qubits = len(qubits) - 1
    oracle = Circuit()

    if randint(0, 1):
        oracle.append(X(qubits[-2]))

    if randint(0, 1):
        return oracle

    on_states = sample(range(2 ** (num_qubits)), 2 ** (num_qubits) // 2)

    def add_cx(qubits, bit_string):
        circuit = Circuit()
        for qubit, bit in zip(qubits[:-1], bit_string):
            if bit == "1":
                circuit.append(X(qubit))
        return circuit

    mct = ControlledGate(sub_gate=X, num_controls=num_qubits)

    for state in on_states:
        oracle.append(add_cx(qubits, f"{state:0b}"))
        oracle.append(mct(*qubits))
        oracle.append(add_cx(qubits, f"{state:0b}"))

    return oracle


def deutsch_jozsa_algorithm(qubits: list[LineQubit], oracle: Circuit) -> Circuit:
    """
    Implements the Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm.

    Args:
        qubits (list[LineQubit]): The list of qubits to be used in the algorithm.
        oracle (Circuit): The oracle circuit representing the function to be evaluated.

    Returns:
        Circuit: The circuit implementing the Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm.
    """
    algorithm = Circuit()
    algorithm.append([X(qubits[-1]), H.on_each(*qubits)])
    algorithm.append(oracle)
    algorithm.append([H.on_each(qubits[:-1]), measure(qubits[:-1], key="result")])
    return algorithm
```

I have tried to make the implementations so that a fair comparison can be made. All the executions were done on a personal computer with 16GB RAM and normal CPU. The expected output was that as the number of qubits increased, the execution time increased linearly or exponentially, but the graph I obtained after averaging 5 different executions for each simulator, shows a strange behavior! Here it is:
[image: Deutsch-Jozsa Runtime by Number of Qubits]

What is the problem?! Is there an implementation error on my part?!

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: Hi @Ahmadrv. Could you provide information (or better, code) about your benchmark methodology? Depending on the order you ran your benchmarks, these spikes *might* be explained by external factors such as another program using the CPU, your laptop going into sleep, or maybe memory issues. I do not think these are the culprits here, but eliminating that directly would help considering other issues.

Comment: Hello @AdrienSuau. I used a simple benchmark methodology for recording the time before and after executing the main function. I ran the benchmark in a loop with bash to increase the number of qubits. The platform I used was a Desktop PC with Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS, which remained active throughout the process. Additionally, I checked the running processes at that time. Therefore, I don't think the issues you mentioned are responsible for the spike. Due to the character limit, I can't post all the code here. I can edit the question or email you the complete code. Thanks for you response

Comment: A few checks then: 
1. can you reproduce this result?
2. can other reproduce this result? (the best would be that you provide enough code to allow anyone to run the same benchmark as you)
3. if both 1 and 2 answers are "Yes", there is definitely something happening and I will try to check it locally on my computer.

Comment: Both answers are "yes!" @AdrienSuau . However, I think, I have identified the reason behind the problem. To obtain an accurate benchmark, we must evaluate the different modes of the oracle separately. This means that we should benchmark the balanced oracle and the constant oracle independently. I evaluated the mentioned oracles independently and surprisingly, the problem was fixed! As this question is a part of my master's thesis, I plan to publish the complete code and documents after the defense.

Comment: If you solved your question, the best way forward would be for you to write down a real answer and mark it as resolved (i.e., auto-answer your question). This will help potential next persons asking themselves a similar question finding more efficiently the answer :)

Comment: Sure. I'm waiting for new results based on the solution. Then, I'll do that. Thanks for your time. :)